# Firestore .endBefore is returning wrong information

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

What I am trying to do is a pagination with the firestore data.

When I use `.startAfter` it returns the correct data, but when I use `.endBefore` always return me the first 10 datas (because of the limit).

If I am in the page 5 and I return to the page 4 it shows me the data of the page 1.

```js
async function newReturnAllRates(limit = 15, before = null, after = null) {
  let rates = [];
  let beforeRate = null;
  let afterRate = null;
  let doc = null;

  const ratesCollectionRef = db.collection("rates");

  if (before || after) {
    doc = await ratesCollectionRef
      .doc(before || after)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          console.log("There are no rates in the database (doc).");
          return;
        }
        return doc;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting last/first document: ", error);
      });
  }

  let query = ratesCollectionRef
    .orderBy("name")
    .orderBy("type")
    .orderBy("subsidiary")
    .orderBy("rate")

  if (doc && doc.id) {
    query = before ? query.endBefore(doc) : query.startAfter(doc);
  }

  await query
    .limit(limit)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log("There are no rates in the database.");
        return;
      }

      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        rates.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
      });

      beforeRate = snapshot.docs[0].id;
      afterRate = snapshot.size < limit
        ? null
        : snapshot.docs[limit - 1].id;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error getting final rates: ", error);
    });

  return { rates, ratesCount, beforeRate, afterRate };
}
```

`before` and `after` are ids. The `limit` value I pass is 10, but by default is 15.

I omit some logic like the `ratesCount` and if the user pass `before` and `after` at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but you may be looking for [`limitToLast`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Query#limittolast) instead of `limit`.